# Is it legal to host user-manual documents on my server?

Tags: legal, content, copyright

Is it legal to host user-manual documents (e.g. a user manual for an lcd television in pdf format) on my server? Also, if I made an HTML page that contains a list of all those hosted documents (again on my server) along with advertisements, would that be described as "redistribution" and if so, would that be legal?

Or maybe this question is too generic and should each document's legality would need to be considered in its own context?

Comment: Do any of these documents contain a copyright notice? If yes, what does it say?

Comment: Generally they are copyrighted.

Comment: Yes, most (if not all) of them contain a copyright notice like "(c) 2009 X Inc. - All rights reserved.".

Comment: So they've reserved all rights and you can't do it.

Comment: Sorry, the only answer is "check with the people that made the manuals".